# Python Multiprocessing for Millions of URLS

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am working on a project that requires fetching millions of URLs and interpreting the fetched data.
Currently the fetching part and processing part is on the same server, which is of course not ideal.

How should I scale this solution? Should there be one server with more memory to do the fetching part? and a second server with more CPU cores which does the processing part.

All data is currently stored in MySQL. Would this be a bottleneck?

I am using Python 3.0 and multithreading.

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing? Estimated time to complete initial loading of data?  What do you have for RAM, Cores, Rotating - SSD - NVME for data storage?  How will you keep the data current?  Cloud or on-premises storage?  Backup and Recovery plan? First-year budget? Second-year budget?